# No me funciona el boton de "ingresar con google"

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, login, google-api

Buenas mi problema es el siguiente:

Usando OAuth 2.0 y la documentación de Google https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview
Cree el botón para ingresar con Google, el tema es que al momento de ingresar me sale la ventana he ingreso mis datos, me tira un error "405 not allowed" en una pagina en blanco [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] No se que estoy haciendo mal o que es lo que me falta agregar. ya tengo bien configuradas las credenciales de Oauth, no creo tener errores en tipeos de url. y no he encontrado ningún tutorial que me pueda ayudar. saludos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>eMercado - Todo lo que busques está aquí</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="contenedor" class="row justify-content-center">
        <div id="central" class="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
          <div id="login" class="login-wrap p-4 p-md-5">
            <div class="justify-content-center">
              <h1>Inicio de Sesion</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="alert"></div>
            <ui>
              <form id="loginform" class="form-group">
                <ul><label for="usuario" class="form-group">Email</label></ul>
                <ul><input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Email"></ul>
                <ul><label for="password" class="form-group">Contraseña</label></ul>
                <ul><input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña"></ul>
                <ul> <button type="submit" title="Ingresar" name="Ingresar" id="ingresar"
                    class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Ingresar</button></ul>
              </form>
            </ui>
            <div class="pie-form">
              <a href="#">¿No tienes Cuenta? Registrate</a>
            </div>
            <div id="g_id_onload"
              data-client_id="627386899527-8lvb5bl5oid593ake3oda12a9pmb2ati.apps.googleusercontent.com"
              data-login_uri="https://micheldiazjap.github.io/home.html" data-auto_prompt="false">
            </div>
            <div class="g_id_signin" data-width=200 data-type="standard" data-size="large" data-theme="outline"
              data-text="sign_in_with" data-shape="rectangular" data-logo_alignment="left">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="text-muted">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Este sitio forma parte de <a href="https://jovenesaprogramar.edu.uy/" target="_blank">Jovenes a Programar</a> -
        2022</p>
      <p>Clickea <a target="_blank" href="Letra.pdf">aquí</a> para descargar la letra del obligatorio.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Según google:*

> El error 405 No Permitido ocurre cuando el servidor web está
> configurado de una forma que no permita que usted pueda llevar a cabo
> una acción para un URL en particular. Es un código de respuesta de
> estado HTTP que indica que el método requerido es conocido por el
> servidor, pero no es soportado por la fuente objetivo.

- Comprueba la URL: Una causa común del error 405 Method Not Allowed es
  la introducción de una URL incorrecta.
- Comprueba la compatibilidad con la versiónes usadas para tu proyecto, php, frameworks, etc.
- Comprueba si hay redirecciones involuntarias, revisa tu archivo .htaccess para ver si hay alguna entrada que
  incluya 405. El mensaje de error 405 Method Not Allowed puede
  aparecer en tu sitio si reescribes el archivo .htaccess
  incorrectamente.

> Busca las líneas que utilizan directivas Rewrite que dirigen a los
> visitantes a una URL. Busca [R=405].
>
> Si está ahí, añade un # al final de la línea. Luego, actualiza tu
> sitio web para ver si esto resuelve el problema.

He encontrado este post [en el foro en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026431/google-oauth2-0-405-error) por si te pueda servir.